# Concatenating binding data

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have the following piece of code for a column in a grid:

```
<dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <Rectangle Width="40" Height="10" Stroke="{ Binding Value, StringFormat='{}#{0}'}" StrokeThickness="5" />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>                                    
</dxg:GridColumn.CellTemplate>
```

The column is bound to a property which has hex values such as:
- aaaaaa
- 123456

So I want to show a rectangle which has color based on the property.

As I've understood, I need to modify my hex values to: 1) include the # sign 2) add alpha channel. The '99' in the formatting is just to test if the thing works with any alpha value - it does not.

How could I get this to work? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a `Binding`, the `StringFormat` property only works on properties of type `String`. As [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.stringformat.aspx) states:

> A string that specifies how to format the binding if it displays the
>   bound value as a string.

The easiest way to solve your problem is to write an [`IValueConverter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter.aspx). This converter will take your input value and return a `SolidColorBrush`.

For instance, if your hex values are strings, the converter's `Convert` method:

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
{
    var str = (string)value;
    var r = Byte.Parse(str.Substring(0, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var g = Byte.Parse(str.Substring(2, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);
    var b = Byte.Parse(str.Substring(4, 2), NumberStyles.HexNumber);

    return new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
}
```